# Can't create folder and file

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm trying to create folder in internal storage of the device, and have some problems with that. I can't create directory using :

```
   String rootPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/test";
    File file=new File(rootPath);
     if(!file.exists()){
         file.mkdir();
    }
```

`file.mkdir` return `false`

I have such permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thank you very much for answers !

Comment: have you done given code?

Comment: If your device is running with Android Marshmallow (API 23) or higher you should ask Runtime permissions.

Comment: Check that you have no file (not a folder) named "test" under your "getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()".

Comment: `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE)`

Should i use this in OnCreate method to call runtime permission ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So really, as you all guys said in Android Marshmallow (API 23) or higher we need to ask runtime permissions.

To solve this issue use call :

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

in your `onCreate()` method

Thanks all for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/test");
        if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
            sampleDir.mkdirs();
        }
```

Comment: result is the same. Folder wasn't create

Comment: what is your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: you can change to  targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: if it is 26 you need to add run time permission, if it is before 23 you it take android permission from android manifest file...